# Person from xxxia: xxxian or xxxitan?

Tags: demonyms

Algeria, Algerian.  Bolivia, Bolivian.  Canadia, Canadian, just to emphasize the preference for -ian.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ian has 2,269 entries, while ...-itan has 4.

So why Samaria, Samaritan?

Comment: "Canadia"? Do *Samaria* and *Bolivia* come from the same language?

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/samaritan

Comment: @nnnnnn It's just like Italia, Italian!